# How to convert a of string to an array of object

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a string which contains values in some format (it is the output of an sql query). The string format is like this : `'enable id \n =============\nf   avc-qwqwq\nt abd-rrtrtr\n f rec-yyuyu \n')`

So, the first 2 values are the column names of the sql and the rows are inside the \n values. So, I have 2 extract these values and pass it as an object.So, I am able to get the values in a list, but can't figure out how to pass these values as an object.

My code looks like:

```
result = ('enable id \n =============\nf   avc-qwqwq\nt abd-rrtrtr\n f rec-yyuyu \n')
n=2
r = result.split('\n')
newlist = r[n:]
print('r', newlist)      //Output : r ['f   avc-qwqwq', 't abd-rrtrtr', ' f rec-yyuyu ', '']
```

Now, how to make an object which looks like:

```
[{
 'enable':'f',
 'org':'avc-qwqwq'
},
{
'enable':'f',
 'org':'abd-rrtrtr'
},
{
'enable':'f',
 'org':'rec-yyuyu'
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = ('enable id \n =============\nf   avc-qwqwq\nt abd-rrtrtr\n f rec-yyuyu \n')

# Extract first two rows.
header_str, _, *rows_str = text.splitlines()

# Parse field names from headers' row.
header = header_str.split()

# Create list of objects mapping words to respective field names from header.
objs = [dict(zip(header, row_str.split())) for row_str in rows_str]

print(objs)
# [{'enable': 'f', 'id': 'avc-qwqwq'}, {'enable': 't', 'id': 'abd-rrtrtr'}, {'enable': 'f', 'id': 'rec-yyuyu'}]
```

This assumes your row values are separated by whitespace. If not, you'll have to change the `row_str.split()` part to extract field values from a row.

---

Here's a Python 2-compatible version:

```
text = ('enable id \n =============\nf   avc-qwqwq\nt abd-rrtrtr\n f rec-yyuyu \n')

iter_lines = iter(text.splitlines())

# Extract first two rows.
header_str = next(iter_lines)
_ = next(iter_lines)
rows_str =list(iter_lines)

# Parse field names from headers' row.
header = header_str.split()

# Create list of objects mapping words to respective field names from header.
objs = [dict(zip(header, row_str.split())) for row_str in rows_str]

print(objs)
# [{'enable': 'f', 'id': 'avc-qwqwq'}, {'enable': 't', 'id': 'abd-rrtrtr'}, {'enable': 'f', 'id': 'rec-yyuyu'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Will it work on both Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: @parami No, it uses syntax that was introduced in Python 3. However, Python 2 has been out of support for [four years now](https://devguide.python.org/versions/), so it hasn't had bugfixes or security updates since then. Highly recommend you not to use it anymore. But I've added a new snippet that supports both versions.

Comment: oh okay, but the requirement was that the code has to be compatible on both of them as it will be running in a server that Python 2 as well. Can you please suggest a method that works on both.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = 'enable id \n =============\nf   avc-qwqwq\nt abd-rrtrtr\n f rec-yyuyu \n'

# Split the string into lines and remove the empty lines and separators
lines = [line.strip() for line in result.split('\n') if line.strip()]

# Get the column names from the first line
column_names = lines[0].split()

# Initialize an empty list to store the dictionaries
data = []

# Iterate over the lines starting from the second line
for line in lines[2:]:
    # Split the line into columns and zip with column names to create a dictionary
    row_dict = dict(zip(column_names, line.split()))
    # Change the key 'id' to 'org'
    row_dict['org'] = row_dict.pop('id')
    # Append the dictionary to the list
    data.append(row_dict)

print(data)
```

this should produce what you have wanted. `org` instead of "id"

Comment: Good idea with `dict(zip(header, row_str.split()))`, it's cleaner than my dict-comprehension. And `str.split()` automatically removes empty spaces, so you don't need `line.strip()` at the beginning.